# How to accumulate and appy gradients for Async n-step DQNetwork update in Tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement [Asynchronous Methods for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf) and one of the steps requires to accumulate the gradient over different steps and then apply it. 
What is the best way to achieve this in tensorflow?
I got so far as to accumulate the gradient and I don't think is the fastest way to achieve it (lots of transfers from tensorflow to python and back). 
Any suggestions are welcome. 
This is my code of a toy NN. It does not model or compute anything it just exercise the operations that I want to use.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from model import *


graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

    state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 80,80,1])

    with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
        W = weight_variable([8, 8, 1, 32])
        variable_summaries(W, "layer1/W")
        b = bias_variable([32])
        variable_summaries(b, "layer1/b")
        h = conv2d(state, W, 4) + b
        activation = tf.nn.relu(h)
        pool1 = max_pool_2x2(activation)

    print(pool1.get_shape())
    pool1 = tf.reshape(pool1, [-1, 3200])

    with tf.variable_scope('readout'):
        W = weight_variable([3200, 3])
        b = bias_variable([3])
        logits = tf.matmul(pool1, W) + b
        variable_summaries(h, "y")

    action_indexes = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="action_indexes")

    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, action_indexes)

    starter_learning_rate = 1e-6

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    # decay every 1000 steps with a base of 0.96:
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,
        global_step,
        10000, 0.96, staircase=True)

    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate)

    gradients_and_variables = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())

    discounted_values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as s:

    for v in tf.trainable_variables():
        print(v.name, v.dtype, v.get_shape())

    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    feed_dict= {
        state : np.zeros([1, 80, 80, 1]),
        action_indexes: [1],
    }


    var_to_grad = dict((var.name, grad) for grad, var in gradients_and_variables)
    keys = sorted(var_to_grad.keys())
    print(keys)

    name_to_var = dict((var.name, var) for _, var in gradients_and_variables)

    for i in range(10):

        gradients = s.run([ var_to_grad[k] for k in keys], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        for k,v in zip(keys, gradients):
            var_to_grad[k] += v

    for k in keys:
        print(var_to_grad[k])

    s.run( optimizer.apply_gradients( (g, name_to_var[v]) for v,g in var_to_grad.iteritems()), feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

---

Updated code after @yaroslave suggestion:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from model import *


graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

    minibatch = 32
    state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[minibatch, 80,80,1], name="input")

    with tf.variable_scope('layer1'):
        W = weight_variable([8, 8, 1, 32])
        variable_summaries(W, "layer1/W")
        b = bias_variable([32])
        variable_summaries(b, "layer1/b")
        h = conv2d(state, W, 4) + b
        activation = tf.nn.relu(h)
        pool1 = max_pool_2x2(activation)

    print(pool1.get_shape())
    pool1 = tf.reshape(pool1, [-1, 3200])

    with tf.variable_scope('readout'):
        W = weight_variable([3200, 3])
        b = bias_variable([3])
        logits = tf.matmul(pool1, W) + b
        variable_summaries(h, "y")

    action_indexes = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[minibatch], name="action_indexes")

    loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, action_indexes)

    starter_learning_rate = 1e-6

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    # decay every 1000 steps with a base of 0.96:
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,
        global_step,
        10000, 0.96, staircase=True)

    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate)

    trainable_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
    varname_to_var = dict( (v.name, v) for v in trainable_variables )
    keys = sorted(varname_to_var.keys())

    gradients_and_variables = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, [ varname_to_var[k] for k in keys])

    var_to_grad = dict((var.name, grad) for grad, var in gradients_and_variables)

    name_to_var = dict((var.name, var) for _, var in gradients_and_variables)

    # save the gradients in memory
    var_to_ref_grad = {}
    for k in keys:
        grad = var_to_grad[k]
        print(k, grad.get_shape())
        ref = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(grad))
        ref = ref.assign_add(grad)
        var_to_ref_grad[k] = ref

    discounted_values = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='discounted_values')

    # control when to apply gradients
    compute_gradients_flag = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name="compute_gradients")
    def fn1():
        var_grad_list = []
        for k in keys:
            grad = var_to_ref_grad[k]
            var  = varname_to_var[k]
            var_grad_list.append((grad,var))

        optimizer.apply_gradients(var_grad_list)
        return tf.no_op()

    fn2 = lambda : tf.no_op()

    last_op = tf.cond(tf.equal(compute_gradients_flag, 1), fn1, fn2)

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as s:

    feed_dict= {
        state : np.zeros([minibatch, 80, 80, 1]),
        action_indexes: [1],
        compute_gradients_flag: False,
    }

    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for i in range(10):

        # accumulate gradients
        s.run(last_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: You could keep everything in TF by running `assign` ops that save gradients in Variables instead of fetching the values, and then doing `assign_add` instead of to accumulate

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Do you think TF will add more interfaces for implementations like this? It would be nice if we can use TF for reinforcement-learning as well.

Comment: @SungKim There's an immediate execution interface [in the works](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2595) so you could use standard Python constructs while keeping data on GPU

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov so I updated the code as you suggested, but now the interesting bit is that `tf.initialize_all_variables()` requires to run the operations in the graph to initialize the variables. Maybe I am doing it wrong and I would not have to use initialize_all_variables and just initialize those manually.

Comment: Hm, I don't understand the problem, `initialize_all_variables` should just run the initializers to set the initial value for the vars, what does it run that it shouldn't?

Comment: I think you should add trainable=False in this line ref = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(grad)). If not, the trainable_variables you called before will have the initialisation problem.

Comment: But it seems that this code doesn't reset the accumulated gradients to 0 after applying them to variables. Am I wrong? Is there any new updated code for sharing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to manually accumulate gradients. You can have Tensorflow accumulate them for you by applying the rollout update as a batch.

```
s_list = list_of_states_visited
a_list = list_of_actions_taken
R_list = list_of_value_targets

sess.run(local_net.update, feed_dict={
    local_net.input: s_list,
    local_net.a: a_list,
    local_net.R: R_list
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work to create ops for accumulating gradients, resetting the accumulated gradients, and applying the accumulated gradients (untested!):

```
def build_gradient_accumulators(optimizer, gradients_and_variables):
    accum_grads_and_vars = []
    accumulators = []
    resetters = []

    for grad, var in gradients_and_variables:
        accum = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(grad))
        accum = accum.assign_add(grad)
        accumulators.append(accum)
        accum_grads_and_vars.append((accum, var))
        resetters.append(tf.assign(accum, tf.zeros_like(accum)))

    reset_op = tf.group(*resetters)
    accum_op = tf.group(*accumulators)
    apply_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(accum_grads_and_vars)
    return reset_op, accum_op, apply_op
```