# Effective method for accumulating gradients in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

It appears that there are already a couple questions on 'how to' accumulate gradients in TensorFlow. Here's the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156957/how-to-update-model-parameters-with-accumulated-gradients) and a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289182/how-to-accumulate-the-gradients-and-apply-them-after-several-iterations-in-tenso).

The accepted recommendation, [taken from this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3994#event-766328647), is to do the following:

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
tvs = tf.trainable_variables()
accum_vars = [tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(tv.initialized_value()), trainable=False) for tv in tvs]                                        
zero_ops = [tv.assign(tf.zeros_like(tv)) for tv in accum_vars]
gvs = opt.compute_gradients(rmse, tvs)
accum_ops = [accum_vars[i].assign_add(gv[0]) for i, gv in enumerate(gvs)]
train_step = opt.apply_gradients([(accum_vars[i], gv[1]) for i, gv in enumerate(gvs)])
```

In the training loop we have:

```
while True:
    sess.run(zero_ops)
    for i in xrange(n_minibatches):
        sess.run(accum_ops, feed_dict=dict(X: Xs[i], y: ys[i]))
    sess.run(train_step)
```

I managed to implement a minimal example of this in a [Jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/AidanRocke/7b006ffd89eb00200d582ba4420dc901) but I'm bothered by the ad-hoc nature of the solution. Moreover, as shown in the notebook, when training is run a second time the accumulator poses a problem. It's not clear to me right now how I should address this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem and posted the solution in a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/AidanRocke/0437b624b68337aa0de33d7810146316). The key thing is to reset the default graph when compiling a new graph and running training for a second time in the same notebook.

So we have:

tf.reset_default_graph()

model = mnist_network(seed=42)